# Search bar is unusable on smaller tablet-sized screens

Tags: bug, status-review, design, search, top-bar

I am using Stack Overflow quite a lot (for questioning and answering). Recently, I bought an Onyx Boox Nova 3 Color tablet with has a 7.8″ E Ink color screen with a resolution of 468x624 (in portrait mode). In this resolution I am not able use the search box as it is too small to put any text in and is too wide to start the mobile responsive mode.

This issue can easily be replicated by changing the width of a normal browser window to just about where it jumps to the mobile responsive mode:

[image: roughly tablet-sized browser window with the search bar constricted to an unusable size]

Am I missing something?
If not, can this be fixed?

Comment: Are you unable to input text or unable to *see* the text you did input? At least testing this on a laptop and "changing the width of a normal browser" I could still type and search and merely did not see the input. Which admittedly isn't great either...

Comment: Same problem if I flip my phone horizontally. They’re using the wrong numbers for when to switch UI modes. Good luck seeing a fix. They’re too busy with AI harassments these days.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, "*Are you unable to input text or unable to see the text you did input?*" - both.

Comment: But were you able to discover their other *"Products"*? The priorities are clear.

Comment: @Andreasdetestscensorship, unfortunately, the boox tablet doesn't have a orientation sensor. I can change the orientation manually thou, but that is quiet a hassle to go back and forth.

Comment: @CodyGray, yes, I am able to click on "*Product*" and than select e.g. "*StackOverflow*" (not sure what this has to do with the *search* issue)

Comment: I assume it was a more or less poking fun at the fact that SE is sacrificing the usability of the header (making the searchbar smaller) to fit in the products menu to show off paid products.