# Get rid of the horizontal scrollbar from the top bar somehow

Tags: feature-request, design, top-bar, scrollbar

Can we somehow get rid of the scrollbar on the top bar of the site while browsing on a mobile phone in portrait mode (narrow screen)?

> [image]

It seems that the easiest solution is to hide the "Products" section somewhere, but maybe there are other options, and Products link a very useful for mobile users? As of me, I never tap that link on a regular basis, but I have to scroll the right part of the top bar every time when I want to switch to another SE site from SO.

My question is not about the search bar, as noted in the suggested duplicate *[Search bar is unusable on smaller tablet-sized screens](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424922/search-bar-is-unusable-on-smaller-tablet-sized-screens)*.

My question is about the ***scroll*** bar.
The search bar works normally in my case:

> [image]

Comment: *"It seems that easiest solution is to hide "Products" section"* - yeeeah... Good luck getting them to do that...

Comment: @Tomerikoo thank you for wishing good luck. I believe that it's actually not needed in that **narrow screen** mode.